# Как запустить 2 контроллера в разных Tomcat контейнерах в одном Spring Boot приложении?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

Есть 2 рест контроллера, условно:

```java
@RestController
public class HttpsService {
    private final KeysRepository keysRepo;

    public HttpsService(KeysRepository keysRepo) {
        this.keysRepo = keysRepo;
    }
}
```

и

```java
@RestController
public class HttpService {
    private final KeyPairRepository keysRepo;

    public HttpService(KeysRepository keysRepo) {
        this.keysRepo = keysRepo;
    }
}
```

Эти контроллеры имеют собственные эндпоинты и оба должны работать с одним и тем же репозиторием.

Вопрос: Как запустить контроллер `HttpsService` в HTTPS контейнере, а `HttpService` в HTTP контейнере? Чтобы при этом конфигурирование обоих контейнеров происходило из единого `application.properties` и оба контроллера имели доступ к одним и тем же репозиториям?

Java 11
Spring 2.5.2

---

Удалось только найти [способ запуска одного приложения одновременно на HTTP и HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53968366/10941639), но это не то.
Ещё, как вариант, думаю, можно разнести эти контроллеры в разные приложения и написать ещё третий сервис, который будет выступать просто репозиторием с CRUD операциями, но тогда придётся запускать каждое приложение отдельно, что не очень-то удобно.